# VBA URLDownloadToFileA or URLOpenStreamA from URLMON - Asynchronously

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous

I'm using URLDownloadToFileA API call to download files in VBA, which works fine (and is *MUCH* faster than WinHTTP or XMLHTTP), but it's synchronous only.

I've been searching for ways to use a URLMon API call asynchronously (perhaps using URLOpenStream instead of download-to-file), but haven't figured out a way to do this.

I stumbled upon VB6 code that might be able to do it here: http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/download/vb6/adl.zip but I am not versed enough in coding to convert this to working VBA.

**Please note:** I do realize how to do this through XMLHTTP and WinHTTP with a class, but those are significantly slower than using the URLMon DLL API, so am hoping to find a solution there.

Code to do it synchronously with URLMon:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFileA Lib "URLMON" (ByVal pcaller As Long, ByVal szurl As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLOpenPullStreamA Lib "URLMON" (ByVal pcaller As Long, ByVal szurl As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As LongPtr

Sub test()
dim a&, b&, URL$

URL = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip"
a = URLOpenPullStreamA (0, URL, 0, 0)
b = URLDownloadToFileA(0, URL, "c:\testfiles\100MB.zip", 0, 0)

End Sub
```

So, this works - but I don't know how to capture the callback for a, and while downloading b it locks excel until the file is fully downloaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think asynchronous and VBA really mix. Why not go with more modern tools like .NET that will allow you to do this?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - sadly I'm bound to an excel specific environment for this. I wish I wasn't, believe me.
VBA and Asynchronous WinHTTP works, but it's still significantly slower than when I'd be able to use URLMon...

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to start the VBA code in a separate Office application, have it exit upon the end of the synchronous download and monitor when it exits from the main application.

Comment: I thought about this, but wouldn't that still hang all office applications while it is stuck on the VBA code? Also, it would show up a bunch of instances, which -if one crashes- makes it messy. Think 100+ threads here...

Comment: You could give it a try but you're better off following Jeremy's suggestion.